# Compare Two Locator Values in Plawright

Tags: unit-testing, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I was wondering if it was possible to compare two page.locator values.

Ex. Say I have a product number that I store in a variable (ex. const poNumber = page.locator(`xpath to element`). I want to take this value and compare it with another page.locator value. Would this be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this with assertions:

```
const poNumber = await page.locators(`foo`).inputValue();
const val2 = await page.locators(`barbaz`).inputValue();
expect(val2).toEqual(poNumber);
```

Or:

```
const poNumber = await page.locators(`foo`).inputValue();expect(await page.locators(`barbaz`).inputValue()).toEqual(poNumber);
```

Or just take both values and do a string comparision:

```
if (poNumber === val2) {...}
```